# How can I center align the contents of a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="sc-content-footer container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/BSY_LOGO_SIGNAGE.png">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
</div>
```

Nothing seems to work, text-align: center does nothing. The content inside the 3 divs is: mailchimp form, logo, mailchimp form

Comment: Need the full code including mailchimp's HTMLs to review

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto`? flex box?

Comment: You can add class `text-center` on cols https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2448/

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap's `text-center` class? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L8330

Comment: could you please provide your stylesheet specifically the .container class?

Comment: [Did you look here?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+div+bootstrap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...I wish I had spent a little more time before asking here. I apologize to everyone, I am new to web design and I got frustrated. Won't happen again.

The problem was Mailchimp's custom CSS. I removed the CSS stylesheet imports from the form HTML, and added Bootstrap classes to the textboxes and buttons. Now everything is fine and dandy.

Answer (score 3):

`text-align: center` only works if the element you are aligning has `display: inline-block`.

Also `text-align: center` is not on the element you are aligning, but on the parent of the element you are aligning.

```css
.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.outer {
  blackground-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in css the outer DIV has:

> position: relative;

and inner DIV has

> position:relative; margin:0 auto;

try this, this is correct form.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes tricky when the `<div>` tags are nested, but please try:

```
.container
{         
     width: 50%; 
     margin: 0 auto;
}

.row
{
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap, you can simply use a Bootstrap class (text-center) to center align the `div` content.

Edit your code to something like this:

```
<div class="sc-content-footer container text-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="images/BSY_LOGO_SIGNAGE.png">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also put the text-center class in the children `div` if you are still having problems after running the above code.